# Devexpress ASPxGridView New Row Disabled

Tags: asp.net, xml, select, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have code like this with devexpress ASPxGridView. Everything goes well, but when I try to add new row, new row's textbox is disabled...
I have KeyFieldName set.

```
 void BindGrid()
    {
       var AnnObj = SearchBarBanners.Select(i => new
        {
            Caption = i.Attribute("caption").Value,
            ID = i.Attribute("id").Value, // this is generated by Guid
        }).ToList();
        ImagesGrid.DataSource = AnnObj;
        ImagesGrid.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: You should post your grid markup.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you two things without grid markup:
1. [Call BindGrid method in Page_Init](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18282.aspx)
2. If your datasource initially returns zero rows, grid won't be able to determine type of objects that will be rendered in grid. You need to use [ASPxGridView.ForceDataRowType](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_ForceDataRowTypetopic) in order to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use recommendations from the [**Q392961**](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q392961.aspx) DX Article to resolve this issue.